# How to copy IMG SRC and paste it on a SPAN element

Tags: jquery, image, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a dynamic php img src and paste it on to the span style background-image. For some reason it's not working for me.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbs img').click(function() {
       var thisUrl = $('.thumbs img').attr('src');
       console.log(thisUrl);
    });
});

// Copy this dynamic php img src (so everytime this img is clicked it also update the span background url)
   <div id="thumbs<?php echo $i;?>" class="thumbs">
      <img src="<?php the_sub_field( 'add_image' ); ?>" />
   </div>

// Paste it here in span 'thisURL' style background-image
   <a href="#" class="lightbox" id="img<?php echo $i;?>">
      <span style="background-image: url('+ thisUrl +');">></span>
   </a>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'd need to target the span in your `click` function and set its style property correctly. Something like ``$('.lighbox > span').css('background-image', `url("${thisUrl}")`)``. HTML just doesn't know about JavaScript variables magically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it but that didn't help mate. Is it possible if you could show a working example please? Thanks mate :)